# Composable data fetching example

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying out the [composable example](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#async-state-example) yet I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
// fetch.js
import { ref } from 'vue'

export function useFetch(url) {
  const data = ref(null)
  const error = ref(null)

  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => (data.value = json))
    .catch((err) => (error.value = err))

  return { data, error }
}
```

Called via:

```
<script setup>
import { useFetch } from './fetch.js'

const { data, error } = useFetch('...')
</script>
```

Yet if I log `data` it's null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` will be null until `fetch()` has completed successfully, you are probably accessing it earlier.

Depending on how you want to handle the loading state, you can either make `useFetch()` async and use it in [async setup](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html#async-setup):

```
export async function useFetch(url) {
  const data = ref(null)
  const error = ref(null)

  try {
    data.value = await fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
  } catch(err) {
    error.value = err
  }

  return { data, error }
}
```

and then in component:

```
const { data, error } = await useFetch()
```

---

Or you also return the promise or a boolean value, so that components can detect if data is loading. Something like:

```
export function useFetch(url) {
  const data = ref(null)
  const error = ref(null)
  const loadingPromise = ref()
  const isLoading = ref(false)

  const doFetch = () => {
    isLoading.value = true
    loadingPromise.value = fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => (data.value = json))
      .catch((err) => (error.value = err))
      .finally(() => isLoading.value = false)
  }
  doFetch()

  return { data, error, loadingPromise, isLoading}
}
```

You can actually use this as you would the async version by awaiting the returned promise during setup.

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref, defineAsyncComponent } = Vue;

function useFetch(url) {
  const data = ref(null)
  const error = ref(null)
  const loadingPromise = ref()
  const isLoading = ref(false)

  const doFetch = () => {
    isLoading.value = true
    loadingPromise.value = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000))
      .then(() => [1,2,3])
      .then((json) => (data.value = json))
      .catch((err) => (error.value = err))
      .finally(() => isLoading.value = false)
  }

  doFetch()

  return { data, error, loadingPromise, isLoading}
}

const AsyncSetupComponent = {
  template: `<pre>{{data}}</pre>`,
  async setup(){
    const {data, loadingPromise} = useFetch()
    await loadingPromise.value
    return {data}
  }
}

const ComponentWithLoading = {
  template: `
    <div v-if="isLoading">Loading...</div>
    <pre v-else>{{data}}</pre>
  `,
  setup(){
    const {data, isLoading} = useFetch()
    return {data, isLoading}
  }
}



const App = {
  components: {AsyncSetupComponent, ComponentWithLoading},
  template: `
    <div class="box">
    Async setup component with suspense:
    <suspense>
      <AsyncSetupComponent/>
      <template #fallback>Loading...</template>
    </suspense>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Component with loading:
      <ComponentWithLoading/>
    </div>
  `
}
createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```css
.box{
  border: 1px solid pink;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example of how I can make it async?

Comment: Have a look at the updated answer. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thanks, sort of, but your first example doesnt work without `<Suspense>` (I think?). Im not sure how you would call your second example?

Comment: Yes, the component with async setup (shouldn't have said async component) needs a `<Suspense>`. Have a look at the updated answer, I have added a snippet which uses both approaches